# Change server variable character_set_server

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I want to change the mysql server variable `character_set_server` to utf8. I have googled on this but can't seem to find the information I'm looking for or the instructions don't match.
It seems I need to edit a file called my.cnf but this file does not exist on my system. The version is 5.1.36.

Comment: Just a note to future visitors here: The OP accepted an answer that is simply wrong (see comments on it to see why). Please see the highest upvoted answer instead. (It's not my answer, and I have no personal stake in this question, this is just a PSA).

Answer (score 16):

this is first result from google

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server

there are two ways to set this configuration

- via configuration file (character-set-server), required restart
- or via `set global/session` character_set_server, this does not require restart, BUT if your database restarted, it will gone, then you will need to set this again

Comment: thanks for for your answer but I don't get why the downvote, that document is not exactly clear for someone who is inexperienced, so I thought I'd ask the question here.

Comment: but is first from the google result :( you should ask at serverfault instead here

Comment: Of course you are right, but the point is: "This option is dynamic, but only the server should set this information. You should not set the value of this variable manually". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli - i provide both ways and explain the aftermath of using manual configuration

Answer (score 3):

**Locations of the my.ini and my.cnf files:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html

As to the question whether you should use **my.ini or my.cnf** files, the above documentation states that

Windows systems use both my.ini and my.cnf,

Linux, Unix, Mac OS X systems use my.cnf.

Comment: what does mean "windows use both"? they have a priority, or it take a random value from one of them?

Comment: Long ago. Can't remember. Looking at the linked resource - see table 4.1- it reads %WINDIR%\my.ini, %WINDIR%\my.cnf  C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf . I interpret that as either one or the other.

Comment: if they are both, in the first (cnf) the value is "A", in the second (ini) is "B", what should we expect to be used?

Answer (score -25):

Run this query:

```
set global character_set_server = utf8;
```

then restart mysql.
you can see the list of all your variables with a simple

```
show variables;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If you run the query and restart MySQL, you will have exactly the same character_set_server as before you issued the query, which might or might not be utf8. Restarting mysql reloads the configuration from disk.

Comment: You don't seem to know the basics of MySQL. So, please, at least TEST your answer before posting them.

Comment: to OP @grai, please, remove this answer as selected answer, because it's erroneous.